# Cannot Register app for GCM in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate GSM in my android app. I am able to run my app and register device through it.

My custom receiver method "GCMReceiver.getGCMIntentServiceClassName" is executed but when GCM tries to instantiate my gcm service (TestService) I get
the following on LogCat:

"Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=test.example.app
cmp=test.example.app/com.activate.gcm.GCMIntentService not found"

Any idea?

My activity code:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this); 
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), "<SENDER_ID>");
```

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission android:name="test.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="test.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="test.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="test.example.app.GCMReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="test.example.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".TestService"  android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

GCMReceiver class:

```
package test.example.app;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {     
    @Override
    public String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return "test.example.app.TestService";
    }
}
```

TestService class:

```
package test.example.app;

public class TestService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public TestService() {
        super("SENDER_ID");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your TestService class placed in? Is that the main package or in a sub package?

Comment: Where does `com.activate.gcm.GCMIntentService` come from? It's not defined anywhere in the code you posted. Perhaps you renamed some of your classes and didn't re-build the project properly. Try to clean and re-build.

Comment: Just for the check, I have create new project put on it only the Activity + TestService + GCMReceiver + I used the same 
Android Manifest. 
All the classes were put under the same package, and I still got the same error message.

By the way, I have download the google-play-services_lib, added it to my PackageExplorer and referenced it from my project in order to be able to use GCMRegistrar

Answer (score 0):

Try to change TestService name to GCMIntentService (rename it).